# R - dynamic reference to a data frame used within a function

Tags: r, function, variables, reference

I have a data frame "MyFrame" and I want to create a function which would reference dynamically some elements from this data frame.

```
A B  
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
```

I want the function to do the following calculation

```
myfunction(rownumber)=(B[rownumber]-B1)/sum(B1:B[rownumber])
```

I am trying something like this but it is not working.

```
myfunction <- function(x) {
    myfunction <- (MyFrame$B[x]-MyFrame$B[1])/(sum(MyFrame$B[2:x])
return(myfunction)}

myfunction(4)=(14-11)/(11+12+13+14)=0.06
```

I guess it is because the reference is done incorrectly. How this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you expect?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(MyFrame)
MyFrame[,C:=(B[x]-B[1L])/sum(B[1:x])]
```

Comment: excellent, it does the calculation! if I would take it further and employ this function to create column C populated with corresponding values , what would be the best way to do it? can this be applied to the whole column at once?

Comment: sorry, q was a typo, it meant to be x